# Show user card or badges on blog

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair, user-card

I have looked in the SO FAQ and searched for this, but have not found it.

Is there a way to show our SO user card or badges on a blog? Perhaps by means of an embedded URL?

Comment: You mean like [flair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/213798/rhughes/flair)? Click the little "flair" link on your user profile

Comment: Or, more for the OP: [rhughes flair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/213798/rhughes/flair)

Comment: The image file shall be: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1213006.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As meta.michael said: "You mean like flair? Click the little "flair" link on your user profile"

Thanks, I never noticed that before.

Comment: In the "Edit Profile & Settings Tab"